# React using Axios GetMethod

Tags: reactjs, spring

I want to pull current BTC prices with Bitcoin API. Backend is working but frontend is not working.

SERVİCE.JS

```
   export default class bitconService {
  
    getBitcoin(symbol){
        return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/btc/avgprice" ,symbol)
    }}
```

bitcon.js

```
export default function Bitcoin() {

  const initialValues = { symbol: "BTCUSDT" };

  const schema = Yup.object({
    symbol: Yup.string().required("sembol zorunlu")
  })


  return (

    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={schema}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        let bitconService = new BitconService();
        bitconService.getBitcoin(values).then(toast.success("aranıyor"))
      }}

    >

      <Form className="ui Form">

        <BtcTextInput name="symbol" placeholder="coin name"></BtcTextInput>
        <Button color="green" type="submit">Ekle</Button>
      </Form>


    </Formik>)}
```

BTCTEXTINPUT.JS

```
  export default function BtcTextInput({...props}) {
    const [field,meta] = useField(props)

    return (
      
             <FormField error={meta.touched && !!meta.error}>
           <input {...field} {...props} />
           {meta.touched && !!meta.error ? (
                <Label pointing basic color="red" content={meta.error}></Label>
           ):null}
        </FormField>
     
    )}
```

swagger ss ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk59A.png)

REACT ERROR SS :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kgri.png)

BACKEND DESC::
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{"code":-1105,"msg":"Parameter 'symbol' was empty."}]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is being passed to the `getBitcoin` service method, but it's most likely that you forgot to pass an object to the `axios.get` method containing `symbol` parameter like so

```js
getBitcoin(symbol){
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/btc/avgprice" ,{ symbol })
}}
```

Comment: I'll need you to provide more context for me to go on here, I see that you are not querying the endpoint correctly,
you would want to pass a string `symbol` but seems like you are passing an object instead which you can tell by the error message as the endpoint contains `[object%20Object]`.